# Opencv problem - imshow() commands doesn't work properly

Tags: python-3.x, video-capture, opencv, python

I have a weird problem with opencv module. I coppied the code from a youtuber named Sentdex. (https://youtu.be/Jvf5y21ZqtQ) For some reason it works for him but not for me. Also to mention I am new to this module so I am trying to learn it. If anyone have an idea I would be really thankful if you would help me.Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Here is the event log:

> *C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Codes/Python/Open cv/Face recognitio.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Codes/Python/Open cv/Face recognitio.py", line 8, in 
>       cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
>   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'*

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `cap.read()` returns empty image. Probably because you don't have camera 1. Try changing it with `VideoCapture(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `cv2.VideoCapture(1)` only if you have two cameras connected.
Replace this line with `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` it solved the problem for me